# Why window.getComputedStyle() returns an object with a property name "backgroundColor" but using a property name "background-color" also works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getcomputedstyle

This is true at least in Chrome and Firefox:

```
Object.keys(getComputedStyle(document.body)).includes("backgroundColor")  // => true
Object.keys(getComputedStyle(document.body)).includes("background-color") // => false
```

yet,

```
getComputedStyle(document.body)["background-color"]    // "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
getComputedStyle(document.body)["backgroundColor"]     // "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
```

So if `background-color` is not a key, how can

```
getComputedStyle(document.body)["background-color"]
```

show something? I know in jQuery, `fontSize` is the same as `font-size`, etc, but if it is property value access it is against the rule of how to access the property value of an object. Can any JS object behave like this?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no magic necessary to see that behaviour alone: `Object.keys` only returns own, enumerable, string-named properties. Any JS object can behave like that by having `"background-color"` either be

1. higher on the prototype chain, or
2. non-enumerable.

The former is true of `"background-color"` on current Firefox, where it’s a getter/setter pair on the prototype of the computed style:

```js
console.log("background-color" in getComputedStyle(document.body));
console.log(
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(CSS2Properties.prototype, "background-color"));
```

Chrome seems to use magic, where hyphenated aliases are enumerable properties that aren’t enumerated.

```js
for (let prop in document.body.style) {
  if (prop === "background-color") {
    console.log("found it");
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document.body.style, "background-color"));
```

Non-host objects – proxies, specifically – can still behave like that, though.

```js
const magic = new Proxy({
  "background-color": "red",
}, {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return [];
  },
});

console.log(Object.keys(magic));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(magic, "background-color"));
```

Comment: if I do `obj = getComputedStyle(document.body)` and keep on showing `obj.__proto__` and `obj.__proto__.__proto__` I don't see such a property named `background-color` either

Comment: Yet `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.getComputedStyle(document.body), "background-color")` results in `{value: "rgb(255, 255, 255)", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}` and `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).hasOwnProperty('background-color')` -> `true`. Either I'm missing something, or the browser is lying

Comment: @Ry- `Object.keys(obj.__proto__).includes("background-color") // => false`

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Hm, it might be magic on Chrome. Not on Firefox.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj.__proto__).includes("background-color")` is actually true on Firefox and false on Chrome... it is "Getter & Setter" on Firefox... not values. It'd be a surprise if the value is on the prototype, because that's supposedly shared by all objects created by that constructor function

Comment: the getter and setter on Firefox is just like an alias then?

Comment: @nopole: Yes.︁︁

Comment: CSS2Properties, by the way, is a DOM Level 2 Style thing. CSSStyleDeclaration is the modern version. The relevant part of the current draft might be at https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute, but I don’t know where enumeration is specified, if it is.

Comment: [Relevant discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1089) (only FF has it per specs)